# Find number of row in mysql

Tags: mysql, row

How can I find the number of row under a specific ID? As an example: If my database is like this

```
  id    |   name    |   email
  1     |   abcd    |   abcdd@xyz.com
  2     |   efgh    |   efgh@xyz.com
  13    |   ijkl    |   ijkl@xyz.com
```

Then, how I find the the number of row after the id '1'. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are looking for the next higher ID?

Comment: Or the number of rows with a higher ID than the given one?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution

```
select count(1) from table where id>1;
```

Comment: what does 'limit 1' signifies?

Comment: limit 1 means the query will return only one value

Comment: Ok thanks, its edited anyway Gouda Elalfy is already given the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use count:

```
select count(*) from table where id>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two part question. The second has been answered by others, but find the total number of entries under a single ID would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = '1';
```